# Can a C# Form application run without Application.Run?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a library that I originally created in Java, but I want to rewrite it (and update it) in C#.  I've found IKVM, and I might have to go that route.  But my first choice would be to rewrite the library in C#.

The library is a teaching tool reminiscent of turtle graphics or Karel the Robot.  So I need to be able to open a non-modal window while still sending commands from the Main method.

To mimic the original, I would like to use code similar to what is shown below to start the program since that would reinforce the typical way that objects are declared and instantiated. As the name implies, MyCustomForm would be a subclass of Form.

MyCustomForm myform = new MyCustomForm(...);

I've searched through the site, but haven't found any other question similar to mine.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The Application.Run call starts the message loop that the application (and the main window) uses to process user input etc. The UI cannot run without a message loop.

Comment: Sounds like whatever you're doing in the main thread should actually be done in another thread, so that your main thread can become a dedicated UI thread.

Comment: Removing `[java]` as the answer doesn't appear to be about Java.

Comment: Do you just want multiple forms running? In your main form you can do myform.Show() to display the custom form as a non modal window.

Comment: The window/form is a display representing a "world" that characters interact in.  The student writes code that will
a.  Create the world
b.  Add characters to the world
c.  Instruct the characters to perform certain tasks within that world.

It is NOT a typical Windows Form Application.  The Window/Form does NOT necessarily have to interact with the user at all*.  The code from the Main method contains all of the instructions.

*It would be nice to have a slider that can control the length of the delay between each step.  But that is optional.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is NOT a game.  There is no user input in the traditional sense.  It is a teaching tool along the lines of Turtle Graphics, Karel the Robot, or the AP Computer Science tool Gridworld.

Comment: @James Lucas This will be a library, not an application.  The students write the applications using the classes in the library.  As explained above, each form represents a "world" in which characters (instantiated using other classes) interact.  What I'm trying to achieve is to make it possible for the students to declare and instantiate the various worlds using the same general syntax that the Java version does.  I realize that that may not be possible in C#.

Comment: @Darryl Braaten there might be multiple forms running.  But there would NOT be a traditional main form.  The forms are just to display the results of the code written by the students.  There wouldn't be any user input in the traditional sense.

Comment: @ThomasCowdery You can launch each form in its own thread i.e.
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new MyCustomForm()));
thread.Start();

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are several ways. The easiest would be to call [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) periodically. Here's a short example of how you might write it.

```
    static class Program {
        static bool formClosed = false;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            MyCustomForm form = new MyCustomForm();
            form.Show();
            form.FormClosed += Form_FormClosed;
            while(!formClosed) {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        private static void Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) { 
            formClosed = true; }
    }
```

There exists much better solutions than this example, though. The term you want to Google for is "C# game loop" despite that your application is not a game.

Comment: I googled C# game loop, but I don't think that is what I need either.  I need the window to open and stay open until it gets manually closed.  But I need the rest of the code in the Main method to continue to execute.  I've included some sample code below to illustrate how this works in Java.  I've changed the names to try to make it easier for you to see what the various classes are for.

Comment: Here is an example of what the code in the Main method might look like. This is a teaching tool that I created and used in Java. I'm trying to recreate it in C#. 

'
    MyCustomForm world = new MyCustomForm(10, 15);//dimensions of an enclosed table. 
    Actor actor1 = new Actor(); //a entity that can interact with the world
    world.AddActor(actor1); //adding the entity to the world 
    for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)   actor1.Forward();
    actor1.TurnLeft(45);  
'
Students write code like above and see the actor follow their directions.

Comment: I can't get the code block to show up right.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Application.Run` *is* a main UI loop, and it just does it better than this.  This is just a strictly worse version of it.  If the OP actually needs a main UI loop, they should just be calling `Application.Run`.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible.

Application.Run() starts the event pump which allows your application to respond to events.  This includes events that come from the user (e.g. clicks, drags, maximize, close) and events that come from the O/S or your own program (such a request to repaint the window, respond to timers, shut down when the O/S is being shut own).  All windows forms applications require this sort of event pump in order to provide typical functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Perhaps you missed my earlier comment that my form will NOT need any typical functionality.  In fact, it only needs to stay open until it is closed.  This is for a VERY atypical use.  I've been able to do this in Java, but perhaps it can't be done in .NET. :-(

Comment: Not sure I understand what it is you are doing, but I must point out that "typical functionality" in this case includes the ability for a form to paint itself, e.g. if another window is on top of it and is then removed.  If the form isn't going to have to paint anything I guess I don't understand why you are writing a forms application to begin with.

Comment: It is a visual tool for teaching programming inspired by Turtle Graphics of Logo and Karel the Robot from Pascal.  In my Java version, there are classes that represent a virtual world, and actors that interact in the world.  The world is just a subclassed JFrame. In the main method, students instantiate the world and actors and write code instructions to solve a problem related to the virtual environment. It DOES behave more like a console application, but they get to see their instructions carried out visually.

Comment: That is why I cannot use Application. Run().  The code that goes AFTER the window opens must be able to run while the window is open.

Comment: It will have to paint itself.  If it cannot do that, then I may not be able to use C#.

Comment: Do you know if this is the way forms work in ALL of the .NET languages?  There's no way to have the window open but take commands from main method?

If so, then I need to abandon my current plan altogether and rewrite my code in Java instead.

Comment: Not sure what "take commands from main method" means, but I doubt it is mutually exclusive with `Application.Run`()`. Have you tried it?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, just use ShowDialog() on your form, simple like that, then when your form closes call Application.Exit(). There is no need for Application.DoEvents();
In my case I'm using this to allow user to login again with another user.
So I can close my main form e then show user login form again

Comment: There's no real reason to do this instead of using `Application.Run`.  `Run` exists specifically for this purpose, and while `ShowDialog` *is* deigned to create a message loop when none exists, it doesn't semantically indicate the creation of a message loop the way `Run` does, and you don't gain anything out of using `ShowDialog`.

Comment: As I already told my reason(but u can't read), this allow user to do loggin again, So I can close my main form and open login form again. If I use Application.Run instead it will close my application.  I'm already using this on my ERP and its works perfect.

Comment: You can do that just fine when using `Application.Run`.  There's nothing that `ShowDialog` does differently in that regard.